# How to hide BottomNavigation icons?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

few days ago I've started learning about reactjs + material-ui library and I'm trying to figure out
how to hide icons from the `BottomNavigation`, ie:

[image: showcase]

I've created a mcve at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hertz-ukbpv?file=/src/App.js:666-682).

Also, when I click on the Login button I'd like to know which button from the BottomNavigation has been selected in order to display a message that says something like:

```
alert(`Page ${name_of_selected_screen} is selected`)
```

how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, to hide the icon is just necessary to remove `icon` props from `BottomNavigationAction`. This is the easy part.

To pass screen selected from `SimpleBottomNavigation` to parent `App` it's a little bit more tricky. First of all you know that from `BottomNavigation` `onChange` function you retrieve the id of the page selected. So you could create a constant array in `SimpleBottomNavigation` to map correlation between index and page name. Something like:

```
const pages = [
   { page: "Page1", id: 0 },
   { page: "Page2", id: 1 },
   { page: "Page3", id: 2 }
];
```

Ok, now we have to pass data from `SimpleBottomNavigation` to `App`. You could do this by add a prop on `SimpleBottomNavigation` like:

```
<SimpleBottomNavigation pageSelected={setPageSelected} />
```

The function `setPageSelected` looks like:

```
const setPageSelected = (page) => {
   setPage(page);
};
```

Where `setPage` is the set state action for `page` state:

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState("");
```

Well, now on `BottomNavigation` `onChange` lets call `pageSelected` like:

```
props.pageSelected(pages.filter((el) => el.id === newValue)[0].page);
```

This works but there is a problem with the first page selected. At start up, if you don't click any `BottomNavigationAction`, the `page` in `App` is not setted.

We can solve this by using `useEffect` and `useRef` hook on `SimpleBottomNavigation` like:

```
const firstrender = React.useRef(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (firstrender.current) {   // this is just a technique to run below code just one time
      props.pageSelected(pages.filter((el) => el.id === value)[0].page);
      firstrender.current = false;
    }
  });
```

Now it's just necessary to modify button Login `onClick`:

```
<Button
   onClick={() => {
      alert("Page: " + page + " is selected");
   }}
>
   Login
</Button>
```

Done! Now alert shows page selected on `SimpleBottomNavigation`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-grass-v4196?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, your answer is just perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem @BPL :)

Answer (score 1):

> How to hide BottomNavigation icons?

The easiest way to hide UI elements it to not render them. Or another way to ask your quesiton is: how do I sometimes **show** a button and sometimes not?

To do this in React, we use conditional rendering that looks something like this:

```
{ showRestore ? <BottomNavigationAction label="Page1" icon={<RestoreIcon />} /> : ''}
```

Now you need a way to set `showRestore`. This can either be a prop that is passed in to your component or component state or global state. The exact solution to use here depends on where you determine whether or not to show the button.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer... I understand why you thought my real question was to figure out how to hide/show the icons conditionally but actually what i wanted to know was how to not using icons at all... for some reason i thought the `icon` attribute was mandatory but it seems is not :/ so if i don't use it the icon won't be shown. I guess your answer about providing conditional rendering is more interesting... What about knowing which BottomNavigationAction is selected? +1 in the meantime

Comment: Sorry, one offtopic question... on this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hertz-ukbpv?file=/src/App.js), is there any easy way to increase the width of the `BottomNavigationAction` that says `""Page2 with a lot of tex"` so it's not splitted in 2 lines? :)

Comment: @BPL Each post on Stack Overflow should be a single question. When you have multiple questions like you do here, you should post them each separately. See [help] for more guidelines about how to use the site.